# Collections.SynchronizedList implementation - synchronized method vs mutex

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, concurrency

The implementation of methods in java.util.Collections.SynchronizedList is using synchronization on a mutex. Given that in all the methods, the complete method body is under the synchronized block, why couldn't it be written as synchronized methods?

Basically:

```
public boolean doSomething(Collection<?> coll) {
    synchronized (mutex) {return c.doSomething(coll);}
}
```

vs.

```
public synchronized boolean doSomething(Collection<?> coll) {
    return c.doSomething(coll);
}
```

I didn't scan all the classes, but may be the reason is that somewhere some method needs partial synchronization (i.e. not the whole method body), and because of them extending the same base class (SynchronizedCollection), the implementation happened to be using mutex to have that finer control. Is that correct? or is there any other reason, like performance, for this choice of implementation?

Comment: Because it allows you to get the mutex, and use that to lock other things.

Comment: The latter form will lock the `SynchronizedList` itself whereas the former can lock some other object.

Comment: Right, I think I didn't really notice initially that there was actually a use case in Vector (and that seems to be the only one that's passing mutex explicitly) which would have warranted this impl. I'll dig that further to understand why vector needs that in general (off this question). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why couldn't it be written as synchronized methods?

There is a [package-private factory method for `SynchronizedList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.synchronizedList%28java.util.List%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) and [corresponding package-private constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java#2402) which allows the list to be constructed with a mutex other than the list itself.

You can't use it directly, but there will be usages of it within the `java.util` package.

One example is in [`SynchronizedList.subList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java#2448):

```
    public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            return new SynchronizedList<>(list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex),
                                        mutex);
        }
    }
```

i.e. accesses to the sublist are synchronized on the parent list, not the sublist.

Another example is [`Vector.subList` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Vector.java#1038):

```
public synchronized List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
  return Collections.synchronizedList(super.subList(fromIndex, toIndex),
                                      this);
}
```

i.e. accesses to the sublist are synchronized on the `Vector`, not the sublist.

Comment: Thanks Andy, got it. Right, I didn't notice initially that there was actually a use case in Vector (and that seems to be the only one that's passing mutex explicitly) which would have warranted this impl. Thanks for the help.